# How can I fix my css style not interpereting?

Tags: html, css

My css file is not changing the thhing i need:

Here's my html:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="/www/style.index.html.css"></script>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="test">Server Test</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's my css:

```
.test{
    font: optional;
    color: red;
}
```

the class test is not working, and I have no Idea why. if you have an answer, please help! :)

Bob

PS: sorry for the weird ass title.. The bot is just stupid

Comment: can u show us the file structure? I guess the `www` folder doesnt exists or the file in not in there

Answer (score 2):

You add/import/link your css file as follows `<link href="./file_name.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

Comment: Good to hear this answer solved your issue.